# Is the graph of integrable function a Jordan set

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $Q \subset R^n$ a box in $R^n$ (meaning $Q = [a_1,b_1]$ x ... x $[a_n,b_n]$).
Let $f:Q \rightarrow [0,\infty ]$ be itegrable on $Q$.

Is the graph of the function $G=$ { $(x,f(x) | x \in Q$ } a Jordan set?

I managed to prove that $G$ is of measure $0$ using Darboux's sums. But is it also Jordan set? or is there an example where it isn't?

Comment: Yes, it is. The fastest way to prove it would be observing that, by definition, for every epsilon there exists a partition $Q_{i,j}$ such that the supremum minus the infimum of $f$ on that partition is less than epsilon; construct the cover of $G$ by $Q_{i,j} \times [m_{i,j}, M_{i,j}].$

Comment: This looks like how I proved that $G$ is of measure $0$

Comment: Here I need to prove that the boundary of $G$ is of measure zero, and I am not very what the boundary is

Comment: I think my argument shows that $\partial \mathrm{G}$ has measure zero and since it is contained in a compact set, it is Jordan.

Comment: But is it a closed set? It is not given that $f$ is continuous, which I think is needed to prove it

Comment: $\partial \mathrm{G}$ is closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87298/discussion-between-will-m-and-gabi-g).